# Can one sibling buy out the others on inherited property?

Tags: inheritance, advice

My sister, who is the personal representative of my dad's estate, wants to buy the inherited house from my brother and I. The market where the property is located is red hot, but she wants to buy us out for a reduced price.

After speaking with a realtor and an appraiser, I am confident that we could get $20,000 more if we put it on the market. The lawyers want to settle and suggested we take the offer.

Is there any way that my brother and I can force my sister to put the house on the market and not accept her offer?

Comment: Does that extra figure account for sales commissions?

Comment: No. I have already subtracted assumed sales commisions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do so by filing a civil action for partition. In these matters, any partial owner of a property can seek a judgment from the court in the jurisdiction where the property is located, which judgment orders the property to be sold and the proceeds divided proportionally between the owners.

The procedures, and costs, and possible sideways trips to arbitration-land, will depend upon the law in that particular jurisdiction.

Comment: Thank you for your help